# I'm not able to understand that how this Node JS method is returning "list of Tasks"?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node,
and not able to understand that how this JS method is returning "list of Tasks" ?
As i don't have any return type and I have passed **result** as a parameter (form of variable) and in last it is used like a method, return like **result(null,err);**. So my confusion is that how it is processing ?

**From TaskModel**

```
let sql = require('./DbConnection.js');
TaskModel.allTasks = function getAllTasks(result) {
        sql.query("select * from task_tbl", function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error In Fetching Records..! \n Error : " + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
                result(null,err);
            } else {
                console.log('All Tasks : ', res);
                result(null, res);
            }
        })
    }
```

I'm calling above method in controller..
**From Controller :**

```
let taskModel = require('../model/TaskModel');

module.exports.list_all_tasks = function (req, res) {
    taskModel.allTasks(function (err, task) {
        console.log("Get All Tasks methods of Controller.");
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log('Response : ' + task);
        res.send(task);
    })
}
```

Comment: you are selecting all the details from task table  and that is why it is returning. More than node it is query specific. NodeJs is just returning your final response. 
`select * from task_tbl`

Comment: result is a callback function. Show us how you would call the `allTasks` method.

Comment: NodeJS is event based asynchronous programming language. In above, sql.query will return callback which you are handing using callback(function(){}).